# get a transparent nav on top of my page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

My goal is to have a navbar with transparent background, with logo on the left edge and 'work' and 'about' on the right edge of the navbar. Pardon me, my page is not responsive right now so correct results will appear only in large viewport. I have created some content inside of my div with container class and want the nav to go on top using flexbox. I needed help how to continue from here. I am trying to replicate [this](http://dejan-markovic.com) design.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  align-content: right;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/pixelplus/image/upload/v1510295441/black-and-white-photography-1024x584_niptgw.jpg");
  background-repeat: round;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30vw;
}

.headline {
  font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  max-width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 33%;
}

.summary {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <nav><a class="logo">logo</a><a class="work">work</a><a class="about">about</a></nav>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="headline">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-direction: row;
max-height: 100px;
align-content: right;
}

nav .logo{margin-left: 15px}
nav .work{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 15px;
 }
nav .about{margin-right: 15px;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/pixelplus/image/upload/v1510295441/black-and-white-photography-1024x584_niptgw.jpg");
  background-repeat: round;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30vw;
}

.headline {
  font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  max-width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 33%;
}

.summary {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <nav><a class="logo">logo</a><a class="work">work</a><a class="about">about</a></nav>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="headline">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @pbenard! I just did not understand why   max-width: initial;?

Comment: You're right, the amx width inital has no sens, because the inital max width was removed.... sorry